# How can I enable new users choose a group when registering on my Django app?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, usergroups

I want to be able to add a group choice checkbox to my user creation form ( signup.html) ( forms.py) so that on registration they get assigned to the group they chose. these groups will have different permissions to access specific models on the site. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all render to all groups to your dropdown.
After you can add selected groups to your user.

```
user=User.objects.create(field=value)
user.groups.add(selected_groups)
```

after you can reach user permissions with
`user.get_all_permissions()` which is django user models gives you.
This function will return selected groups permissions and specific user's permissions